# Como puedo invertir un string para chequear que sea palindrome con python?

Tags: python, string

hola de antemano quiero saber como invertir un string para chequear que sea palindrome. Saludos. se me ha ocurrido hacer un ciclo for y luego cada iteracion insertarla en una lista

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Practica palindromo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/139346/practica-palindromo)

Answer (score 1):

Genera un palabra reversada(reversed) en un método:

```
def esPalindrome(s):
    return s == s[::-1]

print esPalindrome('poop')
```