# Practica palindromo

Tags: python

Tengo duda en como hacer el extra de el siguiente ejercicio

Escriba un método palindromo(frase) que recibe una frase o palabra y devuelve si esta es palíndromo o no.
Luego, escriba un programa principal que solicita al usuario una palabra, envía la palabra al método anterior y luego le dice al usuario si es palíndromo.

Extra: desarrolle un método más complejo, en el cual, se pueden incluir espacios, puntos y comas, pero no son tomados en cuenta, y donde los caracteres tildados son iguales a los no tildados. Debe de funcionar con números también.

Ejemplo para el extra: Oí lo de mamá: me dolió.

La primera parte la desarrolle así:

```
def palindromo(palabra):
   si_es=1
   x= palabra[::-1]
    if x != palabra:
     si_es=0
   return si_es

def principal():
    palis=str(input("Digite la palabra: "))
    if palindromo(palis):
        print("La palabra %s es un polindromo" %palis)
    else:
        print("La palabra %s no es un polindromo" %palis)
```

Answer (score 3):

Una forma bastante general de lograrlo sería, dada la frase que queremos comprobar:

1. Cambiar todas las vocales acentuadas, o con diéresis por las mismas vocales sin acentuar y sin diéresis, a la vez que cambiamos todos los signos de puntuación por espacios.
2. Eliminar los espacios de la cadena resultante
3. Pasar a minúsculas el resultado.

Y luego comprobar si el resultado es un palíndromo.

Para hacer cada uno de los pasos:

1. La función `str.translate()` puede ser de ayuda. Es una función poco conocida que requiere previamente crear un diccionario de traducción mediante `str.maketrans()`. Esta función recibe dos cadenas. En la primera está la lista de caracteres que queremos convertir, y en la segunda la lista de los caracteres ya convertidos (ambas deben ser de la misma longitud). Véase el ejemplo más abajo.
2. Partimos la cadena en palabras usando el espacio como separador (`str.split()`) y juntamos de nuevo todo sin separaciones (`str.join()`)
3. Usamos `str.lower()`.

De paso, se puede simplificar tu código eliminando la variable intermedia `si_es` y retornando directamente `True` o `False`. Con todo ello la función quedará:

```
def palindromo(frase):
    # 1. Quitar acentos y signos de puntuación
    tr = str.maketrans("áéíóúüñÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ.,;!¡¿?", "aeiouunAEIOUUN       ")
    frase = frase.translate(tr)

    # 2. Quitar espacios
    frase = "".join(frase.split())

    # 3. Pasar todo a minúsculas
    frase =frase.lower()

    # Comprobar resultado palindrómico
    if frase == frase[::-1]:
      return True
    else:
      return False
```

He verificado que usando ese código detecta correctamente los siguientes palíndromos famosos:

> Dábale arroz a la zorra el abad.
>
> ¡No traces en ese cartón!
>
> ¿Son mulas, o cívicos alumnos?
>
> Oí lo de mamá: Me dolió.

O este menos conocido (porque lo acabo de inventar :-)

> No types, sé pytón

Answer (score 0):

La forma mas facil es procesar tu palabra reemplazando los caracteres que vas a ignorar y los caracteres con tilde con sin tilde antes de verificar si es palindrome...

```py
import string

def palindromo(palabra):
   palabra_procesada = palabra
   palabra_procesada = string.replace(palabra_procesada, ",", "")
   palabra_procesada = string.replace(palabra_procesada, ".", "")
   palabra_procesada = string.replace(palabra_procesada, " ", "")
   palabra_procesada = string.replace(palabra_procesada, "á", "a")
   palabra_procesada = string.replace(palabra_procesada, "é", "e")
   palabra_procesada = string.replace(palabra_procesada, "í", "i")
   palabra_procesada = string.replace(palabra_procesada, "ó", "o")
   palabra_procesada = string.replace(palabra_procesada, "ú", "u")
   si_es=1
   x= palabra_procesada[::-1]
    if x != palabra_procesada:
     si_es=0
   return si_es

def principal():
    palis=str(input("Digite la palabra: "))
    if palindromo(palis):
        print("La palabra %s es un polindromo" %palis)
    else:
        print("La palabra %s no es un polindromo" %palis)
```

Comment: Tambíen puedes agregar reemplazos por las mayúsculas o la ñ

Answer (score 0):

```
#solo para una palabra, no frases :'(      

  palabra=input("ingrese la palabra a ser analizada: ")
    inver='' #creó un arreglo de string vacío
    t=len(palabra) #averiguo el tamaño de la cadena ingresada
    while t>0:
        t=t-1 #decremento desde el valorfinal o mayor hasta 0 (como se indica en el while)
        print(palabra[t]) 
        inver=inver+palabra[t]  #concatenación de letra por letra, guardados en serie
    print(inver)

    if palabra == inver:
        print('la palabra ingresada es palindroma')
    else: print('la palabra no es palindroma')

#un codigo sin raras funciones, muy basico y funcional, que les vaya bien en su prueba #sin usar funciones prros
```