# Crea una función que lea una frase de teclado y nos diga si es o no un palíndromo usando Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter

Buen día, tengo un ejercicio que realizar en Jupyter, específicamente Python usando la librería de Numpy, radicandolo en una función. Anteriormente había realizado este pequeño código sin usar numpy:

```
def palindromo():
pali = str(input("ingrese la palabra: "))
if (pali) == (pali)[::-1]:
    print("palindromo")
else:
    print("no es palindromo")
return

palindromo()
```

A esto quise quise hacer lo mismo pero usando numpy, aclaro que soy nuevo en esto asi que perdonen si me equivoco o si lo que hago esta por completo mal, mi idea fue la siguiente:

````
L1= ['juana']
pali = np.array(L1)
pali
array(['juana'], dtype='<U5')

def palindromo():
    if (pali[0,0]) == (pali[0,0])[::-1]:
        print("palindromo")
    else:
        print("no es palindromo")
    return
palindromo()

Error:
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-a8a6349f0046> in <module>
----> 1 palindromo()

<ipython-input-54-2ede8003022f> in palindromo()
      1 def palindromo():
----> 2     if (pali[0,0]) == (pali[0,0])[::-1]:
      3         print("palindromo")
      4     else:
      5         print("no es palindromo")

IndexError: too many indices for array```
````

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes! Y bien, ¿cuál es tu problema? ¿Qué intentaste hacer usando numpy?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Practica palindromo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/139346/practica-palindromo)

Comment: Hola @Alfabravo y gracias, en si quiero hacer una función que me permita hacer lo del código anterior pero usando numpy, la he intentado pasar por una lista y creando un array a esa lista pero no he tenido éxito, agradezco cualquier ayuda. :D

Comment: Te sugiero incluir en la pregunta, junto con el código que ya pusiste, los intentos fallidos que mencionas y los mensajes de error o problemas que has encontrado. Así será más fácil que te guíen y encuentres la solución aquí.

Comment: @Alfabravo gracias por la sugerencia, ya hice una modificación de lo que intente hacer.

Comment: Está muy bien tu pregunta! Recuerda que acá sólo somos compañeros (de sufrimiento) ayudándonos, no hay que tener miedo a mostrar nuestros fallos. Hay algunos usuarios con conocimiento profundo de python y seguro te ayudan pronto :)